# CSS при нажатий на кнопку проиграть анимацию

Tags: css, css-animation

CSS

```
.form-item__btn:active::before {
  display: block;
  animation: pressed 1.5s;
}
@keyframes pressed {
  20% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  80% {
    width: 200%;
    height: 300%;
  }
}
```

Я хочу при нажатий на кнопку проиграть анимацию, но как только клик мыши пропадает анимация сбрасывается. Подскажите мне, как я могу реализовать данную идею

Comment: использовать js или checkbox

Comment: Или использовать forward в animation

Answer (score 1):

нужно воспользоваться свойством `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` так же у Вас нет состояния когда 100% анимации и когда 0%. а они должны быть чтобы конец анимации сохранился! пример:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {  document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('active');
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container.active .item {
  animation: pressed 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes pressed {
  0% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<button>start!</button>
```

Comment: а если нужно без JS. Такое можно реализовать?

Comment: @jurvrn заменить .container.active .item на  button:focus ~ .container .item Но как только фокус пропадёт с кнопки,  анимация сбросится. Можно поиграться с псевдокласами у кнопки и найти какое-нибудь решение.

Comment: да вот нет таких состояний, которые бы определяли клик (кроме activity). Но активити длится пока кнопка нажата - только убрал стиль пропадет

Comment: @jurvrn ну замените кнопку на чекбокс и используйте :checked и будет работать. Замаскируйте под кнопку сделав чекбокс hidden и обернув в label. И всё. Но всё это костыли не нужные. Когда просто можно использовать Js

Comment: понял, только нужно ж как-то будет состояние checked снимать.... А так то да - через JS можно любой стиль в виде анимации подключить